# Pandas iterate over values of single column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am a beginner to python and pandas.

I have a 5000-row data frame that looks something like this:

```
INDEX  COL1  COL2  COL3
0      10.0  12.0  15.0
1      14.0  16.0  153.8
2      18.0  20.0  16.3
3      22.0  24.0  101.7
```

I wish to iterate over the values in `COL3` and carry out calculations, such that:

For each row in the data frame, if the value in COL3 is <= 100.0, multiply that value by 10 and assign to variable "New_Value";
Else, multiply the value by 5 and assign to variable "New_Value"

I understand that `if` statement cannot be directly applied to the data frame series, as it will lead to ambiguous value error. However, I am stuck trying to find the right tool for this task, and would appreciate some guidance.

Cheers

Comment: Can you confirm that 'New_Value' and 'New Value' will be different columns?

Comment: is it highly recommended to avoid iteration for operation that can be in vectorized way... the performance it critically less effective...

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.where`:

```
df['New_Value'] = np.where(df['COL3']<=100,df['COL3']*10,df['COL3']*5)
```

Comment: I managed to use this to get my code to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***One liner***

`df.COL1.apply(lambda x: x*10 if x<=100 else 5*x)`

for this example, you can use apply, which will apply a function on each row of your data.

`lambda` is a `quick` function  that you can define. It will have a bit of a difference compared to normal functions.

The condition is => `x*10 if x<=100` so for each x under or equal to 100, multiply it by 10. `ELSE` multiply it by 5.

Comment: @PaulH i said you `can` not you `must`

Comment: @PaulH plus the diversity of answers will enrich the feed for later on researches

Comment: And just because you can doesn't mean that you need to, so we're in agreement. I will say that using the dot-accessor to get columns in generally a bad practice and something to be avoided even more than needlessly looping through the rows of a dataframe (explicitly or implicitly via `apply`)

Comment: @PaulH True, indeed. I agree on this one ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df['New_Value']=df.COL3.apply(lambda x: 10*x if x<=100 else 5*x)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, won't the second line run over the first one? I would do a single line with `.apply(lambda x: 10*x if x<= 100 else 5*x)`

Comment: I think you could do this is you reversed the order, but you'd still be needlessly looping over the array twice

Comment: OP must confirm if there will be one new column or 2 (New_Value and New Value) or it's just a typo

Comment: Either way, the second line will overwrite the first.

Comment: It's 2 different columns. Maybe it's a typo from OP though, please read the question again. Am I the only one that i see that '_' in the middle? You make me scared :)

Comment: Hi everyone. Sorry for the typo! I mean for there to be one new column "New_Value" and have corrected my post.